# self leveling layer with internal French drain

Tags: basement, french-drain, self-leveling-concrete, leveling

I am planning to pour a layer of self leveling sealant such as levelPro to level out my basement floor and cover / encase some possible problematic vinyl tiles.

It's an older house, and I believe it has an internal French drain, though I can't say for sure. It does have a sump pump/pit in the corner of the basement that occasional gets triggered and pumps some water out. I also think it has an internal French drain since the basement floor/ tiles go out to the basement walls, but there's a gap of 1-3 inches in which there are some stones. I think this is covering the French drain.

If this is the case, I want to pour the underlayment without it getting into the French drain. What is the best way to accomplish this? My current thought its that I might tape or adhere some 6 mil plastic sheeting on the edge of the floor right before it becomes stone, and tuck it into the corner where the wall meets the stones, and then run it up the wall a few inches and then adhere it to the wall. Does this seem reasonable, and does it seem like it would cause any issues with the setting of the poured leveling underlayment? If I go this route should I use a thicker plastic?

Please, let me know if this is the best course of action or if I should take another approach.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

How long do you plan to keep the house?

I'd just get the tiles tested and remediated.  How many square feet are you thinking about?

Self level isn't cheap and if you want to make your basement usable at some time in the future you probably want to do something more through.

I've fixed up a number of 1920 basements that had sump pits for ground water collection, no vapor barrier, brick / thin concrete or some other kind of weak terrible floor.

Generally I'd remove the existing floor, remove some dirt, add interior perimeter drains, add a modern sump pit, add a drainage layer, add some insulation, add a radon/vapor barrier, add a pipe for future passive/active radon mitigation, re-pour slab.  Sometimes I underpin the foundation to gain height.